# Web Link inserts value into Textarea

Tags: html, forms

Much like the mailto: link you can add ?subject=
I wanted to be able to create a web link which would send you to a webpage that contained a form.

In that Form, I would like the value of the TextArea to contain information Inserted by the contents of the referring Weblink.

Example:
`example.com/page-url?textarea=content`

Is that possible? If so, can you tell me?
I pay in chocolates.

Thanks for your time and I look forward to any replies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but i think you can make a form with get method `<form method="get" action="example.com/page-url">`.
That's work?  you want convert form to url or complete form with url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain HTML can't do this by itself. You'll need to use Javascript or some kind of server-side processing to get the values from the submission.

Forms have two methods - POST, which submits through the headers, and GET, which submits through a querystring. With the querystring it's easier for users to mess with your data, so keep that in mind as you design this. (Not that it's impossible with POST, but it takes a little more work)

Since you're passing to a textarea, make sure you URLEncode your post or things like spaces will cause you a lot of headaches.